# Firebase admin SDK FCM error Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am fixing an error message which occurred, but it also used to work before. I am sending FCM notification with multiple tokens and am getting the following error

```
0|api      | 2020-2-11 13:26:26   [ExceptionsHandler] Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required
0|api      |  +542752ms
0|api      | Error: Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required
0|api      |     at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/var/www/tokee-api-new/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
0|api      |     at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/var/www/tokee-api-new/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
0|api      |     at new FirebaseMessagingError (/var/www/tokee-api-new/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:254:16)        0|api      |     at Object.validateMessage (/var/www/tokee-api-new/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-types.js:46:15)
0|api      |     at /var/www/tokee-api-new/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:265:31
0|api      |     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
0|api      |     at Messaging.sendAll (/var/www/tokee-api-new/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:264:29)
0|api      |     at Messaging.sendMulticast (/var/www/tokee-api-new/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:313:21)   0|api      |     at userChunks.forEach.userChunk (/var/www/tokee-api-new/src/modules/common/firebase/firebase.service.ts:154:42)     0|api      |     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
0|api      |     at FCMService.<anonymous> (/var/www/tokee-api-new/src/modules/common/firebase/firebase.service.ts:142:16)
0|api      |     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
0|api      |     at /var/www/tokee-api-new/dist/src/modules/common/firebase/firebase.service.js:13:71
0|api      |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
0|api      |     at __awaiter (/var/www/tokee-api-new/dist/src/modules/common/firebase/firebase.service.js:9:12)
0|api      |     at FCMService.sendToMany (/var/www/tokee-api-new/dist/src/modules/common/firebase/firebase.service.js:123:16)       0|api      |     at AdminNotificationController.<anonymous> (/var/www/tokee-api-new/src/modules/notification/admin-notification.controller.ts:65:42)
0|api      |     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
0|api      |     at fulfilled (/var/www/tokee-api-new/dist/src/modules/notification/admin-notification.controller.js:16:58)
0|api      |     at <anonymous>
```

The code producing the error:

```
async sendToMany(users: User[], notification: VSendNotification, title = 'Title', lowPriority = false) {
    // We split emails into arrays of max. 100 size because of the limitation with FCM
    const userChunks = _.chunk(users, 100);
    const promises = [];
    userChunks.forEach(userChunk => {
      const msg: admin.messaging.MulticastMessage = {
        notification: {
          title,
          body: notification.body
        },
        tokens: userChunk.map(user => user.firebaseToken),
        android: {
          priority: lowPriority ? 'normal' : 'high'
        }
      };
      promises.push(this.app.messaging().sendMulticast(msg));
    });
    const result = await Promise.all(promises);
    let accepted = 0;
    let rejected = 0;
    result.forEach(response => {
      accepted += response.successCount;
      rejected += response.failureCount;
    });

    return { accepted, rejected, notification };
  }
}
```

Thoughts on what could be wrong?

Comment: Same happening with me

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Solution** - Avoid sending empty fcm token to Firebase.

I got the solution. I listed all my firebase token and there were some empty tokens in my database which was the main problem.

When we send empty fcm token, Firebase gives us below error

```
Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the answer. Our app had been through a rework and apparently some users' tokens got deleted. Checked and yeah, they were null :)

Comment: Same happening but I don't have empty fcm token

Comment: Kindly check it once again, by printing every token. It could be empty or null.

Comment: In my case,  I was using send instead of sendMulticast

Answer (score 7):

Like the comment mentioned by @vijayst. My Issue was that I was using send(message) and including in my message an array of `tokens`. However, send() doesn't accept that. Send could accept a "topic", but to send to an array of tokens, you need to use sendMulticast(message)

[send](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics)

[sendMulticast](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices)

Comment: we have to use send, sendMulticast properly. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message