# FireBase Admin SDK Java: Sending a notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

I'm trying to send a notification to my Android device using my Java Server with the FireBase Admin SDK.

I can send test notifications from the FireBase website successfully, but I'm having trouble setting it up on Java in my server:

```
    Message message = Message.builder()
    .setNotification(Notification.builder()
        .setTitle("$GOOG up 1.43% on the day")
        .setBody("$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.")
        .build())
    .build();


    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    String response = "N/A";
    try {
        response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
    } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exactly one of token, topic or condition must be specified

Where do I even set the user token here? I just want to send a simple notification using FireBase in Java to my Android FireBase client.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60170040/firebase-admin-sdk-fcm-error-exactly-one-of-topic-token-or-condition-is-require

Comment: @SkywalkerLukeJS I don't think there's a solution in there to my code. I'm trying to send a notification, not a message. Also that person is using NodeJS, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to put .setToken(...) after the line: build())

I was putting it in the wrong place.